# Why do the versions of Thunderbird and Firefox differ in 12.10?

Tags: updates, firefox, thunderbird, mozilla

I noticed, that on my Ubuntu 12.10 Thunderbird is only version 17.06 while Firefox is already on 21.0.

It seems, like the updates of Firefox are somewhat faster?

Do I have to install the [PPA for Thunderbird Beta](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-next) to get more updates?
Or are they unsafe?
(I have a lot of important emails inside my Thunderbird, that I have to keep access.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed, that on my Ubuntu 12.10 Thunderbird is only version 17.06
>   while Firefox is already on 21.0.
>
> It seems, like the updates of Firefox are somewhat faster?

So, it means that you have the latest version of both software. The version of firefox doesn't have to have the same version as thunderbird.

Today, these are the latest versions :

- [thunderbird 17.0.6](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/17.0.6/releasenotes/)
- [firefox 21](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/21.0/releasenotes/)

> (I have a lot of important emails inside my Thunderbird, that I have to keep access.)

In that case, I wouldn't enable additional repositories to install beta or pre-release software, since it can be quite unstable.